# Seeing "It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error" intermittently

Tags: bug, error-message

I have been seeing this a few times while on Stack Overflow. The first time was on April 29th, and I had it just a few minutes ago.

I thought it was only for the "php" tag, but did browse other tags and it was showing the same error. It came back to normal a minute or two later; this for both times I encountered this.

I did not post a question about it the first time I saw this, and decided to post one since this happened to me again and there are others who experienced the same thing. I have never seen this type of error message before.

Is this a new bug or is the network undergoing pre-tests from a post I saw recently that is planned for May 3rd?

- [Brief outage planned for Wed, May 3, 2017 at 8pm US/Eastern (00:00 UTC) (like a fire drill for computers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295285/brief-outage-planned-for-wed-may-3-2017-at-8pm-us-eastern-0000-utc-like-a)

I have also seen these 2 posts on meta stackexchange:

- [Random errors on various sites when viewing main page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295433/random-errors-on-various-sites-when-viewing-main-page)
- [Misleading error message when questions list fails to load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295358/misleading-error-message-when-questions-list-fails-to-load)

Here are two screenshots.

The first was taken on April 29th.

> [image]

and the other about 10 minutes ago:

> [image]

---

**Edit #1:**

It just happened again now, at approximately 9:54 am, EST.

Screenshot:

> [image]

---

**Edit #2:**

This happened again at approximately 10:33 am EST and its frequency seems to be augmenting.

This time I looked at my console and the following showed up:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')' [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_token?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default)   void();:1:5

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: I just saw this on the home page of Meta.SE, except without the "that's a miss".  (Not a search, just the home page.)

Comment: Same thing happened to me just now on the Arqade.SE active page.

Comment: I've been seeing this since I opted into the new tab system (for a few weeks now). Are you opted into that as well?

Comment: Now too for jQuery, JavaScript, HTML

Comment: I just went to see an example of a URL for looking at tagged questions as I was wondering if maybe you had another parameter in there. So I clicked on vb.net in my Favorite Tags list to go to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net` and... there were no questions listed but also no error.

Comment: Website just went down temporarily too - don't know if it is related.

Comment: @JornVernee Yes, I opted into the new tab system for a while now. I don't know if it has anything to do with it though, and if people that are not using it, are affected or not.

Comment: Note, this is not just on SO. At least, other sites gets the same effect on other sites without the message.

Comment: I am getting this too. First appeared 4 hours ago from now. It was mostly on Ruby on Rails and AngularJS tag. I am in new tab system since beginning but never saw this before today.

Comment: @Sinatr Stack just went offline a moment ago. Am starting to wonder if that has anything to do with this Tweet https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/857220467974971392 and in relation to my question.

Comment: @Albzi welcome. I saw the tweet by visiting it after seeing the offline error message when Stack went offline moments ago.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Unfortunately twitter is blocked at work - do you know how often stackstatus.net is updated?

Comment: @Albzi Sorry I don't know. But you can always check http://stackstatus.net/

Comment: There is already a question over at MSE for this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295358/misleading-error-message-when-questions-list-fails-to-load

Comment: *Just for the record*: I saw yet another about 10 mins. ago. I didn't bother re-editing because they are now happening even more frequently; something's up but haven't gotten word from techs about this (yet).

Comment: As of 12:41 pm EST, viewing any profiles shows an `Oops! Something Bad Happened!` message with an image of "WORKING ON UR PROBLEMZ". Edit: 12:45 pm / still in the same state. It's not May 3rd yet ;-)

Comment: I've had it happen a few times recently for the C tag.  It'll persist for a few minutes, then 'goes away'.  But it has been happening more often in the last week or two (2, 3, 4 times?) than it did in the previous year or five (0 times?).

Comment: @Fred-ii- For just a brief, shining moment, the PHP tag was empty. We were free, I tell you. FREE! And then the site came back up.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, this seems to have been growing as time went by. [See the comment I left](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348639/seeing-it-was-not-possible-to-perform-this-tag-search-at-this-time-due-to-an-un#comment470343_348696) under Marc's answer also.

Comment: @Machavity *Haha!*, that we were, but there's just no escaping it ;-)

Comment: It's now happening on Meta: https://prnt.sc/ufk2vy. Edit: Back to normal right after I posted this comment

Comment: Happening on Meta again now (have had it a few times in the last hour or so). When I edited this question the page knew and told me that one new question had activity. When I then clicked that it showed me this very question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q1yF.png). Meta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(repeated from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295358/misleading-error-message-when-questions-list-fails-to-load/295481#295481))

The short summary of this one is "because internet"; it turns out some annoying folks were doing annoying things specifically to be annoying, and a side-effect was disproportionate performance impact to a particular sub-system (the "tag engine"). I sincerely doubt that it was accidental or simply "oops my innocent crawler had an impact on your site? I simply didn't know...", based on the pattern of behaviour and the particular hoops they jumped through to hide their tracks. Anyway, as far as annoying bots go: that's what we call "a day with a 'y' in"; it was low-key enough not to set off any too urgent alarm bells, but it made it onto our radar, as has now been squished.

Comment: Thing is Marc is that, this seems to have been slowly creeping and growing into a bigger snowball. Today was pretty special as those (error) messages showed up on more than one occasion; I actually counted 5 but only posted a few edits and a few comments under the question [Jonathan's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) also made a mention of it. I thought it might have had something to do with the upcoming planned outage on May 3rd (tomorrow). I'll keep an eye on it and log these the best I can, *cheers*.

Comment: I'm curious though; did you see what I posted under **Edit #2**? Is there relevance? (about the syntax error).

Comment: @Fred-ii- no specific connection AFAIK - could possibly be an edge condition where the realtime update code gets confused if the question list failed to populate

Answer (score 9):

I had this happen this morning, but after a couple of reloads the problem went away. However I'm getting it again now. I can confirm the following:

1. No console or network errors are reported back to the browser - it presumably therefore an internally-generated error.
2. Clearing cache doesn't resolve the issue (expected due to #1).
3. Disabling any browser extensions and reloading the page doesn't resolve the issue (again, expected due to #1).
4. Leaving the page open results in new questions coming through (with the usual "*n* new questions" message) as seen in the second image in the original post.

What *did* seem to resolve the issue was simply clicking on the logo to return to the main page and then clicking back on the tag I was trying to search for - although whether this was just coincidence I do not know.

This doesn't seem to be affecting a specific tag, either. Earlier it was occurring for me on [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and just now it was affecting [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors).

---

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: Thanks for the answer James. What I was hoping for was that, a tech would step in the question to shine some light on the subject as to "why" this is happening/happened. That error message was completely new to me and have never seen it before as I stated in the question. I thought caching was at play here but alas it was not. It could be a roaming bug running underneath the carpet or alongside the rafters that keeps jumping around and just can't seem to catch it. *Cheers*

Comment: *"No console or network errors"* - I've made an edit in that regard. Reload the question and look under **Edit #2**.