# Where have all the red flags gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

The post flag dialog looks like this now:

[image: Answer flag dialog]

[image: Question flag dialog]

The **spam** and **rude or abusive** flags are missing.

It hasn't been like this for long and I also have plenty of flags left.

Comment: The spam and rudeness problems have been resolved, the flags are now obsolete. Yay!!

Comment: Question posted on the SE Meta as well https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361613/where-do-the-spam-and-rude-flags-go

Comment: Yeah, this is broken network-wide

Comment: It was working within the last 20 minutes.  I literally used it to flag and delete a spam post on another community.  Which I can't mention otherwise my hidden community will be known.

Comment: You'll just have to create a user script and send the flags "manually" :) I think user scripts are the common workaround here.

Comment: I wonder if it's only the dialog that it's missing those or if the entire flagging API doesn't accept those at the moment.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Using the advanced flagging userscript to try flag while bypassing the dialog results in a permissions error as mentioned in the comments of the MSE post

Comment: @Nick interesting. Meanwhile I also randomly got [this](https://i.imgur.com/35wmaMr.png) by clicking the home link. Weird.

Comment: Fixed per [developer comment on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361613/where-did-the-spam-and-rude-flags-go#comment1206488_361613)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli that seems to happen every now and again, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348639/1364007).