# meta.so seems to be broken - does a server need kicking?

Tags: bug, meta

Does one of the servers need kicking?

[image]

Comment: seems to happen quite often, been seeing this for weeks. always clears up within a minute

Comment: Several refreshes fixed it and I was able to post the question.

Comment: This is related to building - we build, search dies for ~30 seconds. Not sure what the cause is but it's definitely a recurring thing.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348639/seeing-it-was-not-possible-to-perform-this-tag-search-at-this-time-due-to-an-un

Comment: Did you forget you posted the same problem 6 to 8 weeks ago for the same site but on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360522/it-was-not-possible-to-perform-this-tag-search-at-this-time-due-to-an-unexpected ?

Comment: Don't kick the server, that's server abuse!

Comment: @10Rep .. it can also result in painful injuries, especially if the server is right at the top of a 19" rack:)

Comment: @MartinJames Sounds like you're speaking from experience :-P

Comment: @rene Yep. Old age and exhaustion creeping up on me :/