# It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error

Tags: bug, tags, search

Duplicate (ish) from 2017, although it referenced Stack Overflow: [Seeing "It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error" intermittently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348639/seeing-it-was-not-possible-to-perform-this-tag-search-at-this-time-due-to-an-un)

However, I do not see the error on the Stack Overflow site. I only see it here in meta when visiting https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

[image: It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error.]

Similar to the duplicate report, this is intermittent as well. Marc Gravell stated prior that this was due to a version of either attack or exploit.

Just raising awareness.

Comment: I see that issue about once every 6-8 weeks. It seems to clear itself (with page refreshes) within 15-30 minutes as I remember.

Comment: couldn't consistently reproduce myself too - seeing it periodically happen and go away in a short while just as charlietfl mentioned. Maybe if we keep posting the report, someone might do something in about 6-8 time units.

Comment: (Thinking aloud) I wonder whether this happens during deployment

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson is this a hint? :) That might explain the error just appearing and going away without a trace

Comment: A majority of the system appeared to still be running, which I would assume includes logging. That looks like a custom error message, which means that the error should be logged somewhere. There should be some trace remaining, sometimes it just helps to have a starting point to go look.

Comment: I get this error message on a semi-regular basis. I personally think it comes from being rate-limited, but I've done nothing to prove that.

Comment: @CodyGray - I got this from my first request of the day after a weekend of not being on this computer or at this location. First time I had seen this message.

Comment: I got the same now. It is my first session from my current (private) browser window.