# Again: It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error

Tags: bug, error-message

When opening https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ the following error is shown:

> It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error.

Probably related to the deployment of a new (annoying) "tooltip"

[image]

Apparently the other pages are working correctly

- [It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412750/1595451)
- [Seeing "It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error" intermittently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348639/1595451)

Comment: I repro this periodically, too, here on MSO. It's always *extremely* transient. As I understand, it's either Internet issues *or* Stack Exchange doing a deploy/software update.

Comment: @CodyGray This afternoon "New!..." tooltip is shown to me multiple times (I jump across sites multiple times... it's annoying)

Comment: I also get it quite frequently on MSO, specifically. Sometimes, it lasts for up to a minute or two. I just learned to ignore it, but hopefully, we can get a definitive answer from staff and/or a permanent fix.

Comment: The new tooltip is actually pretty annoying, it keeps showing up when I go to different sites

Comment: Happened again for a full minute or so. This seems not-so "transient" but more "periodic".